# seleccionar todas los options de un select con jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, select2

```
function autos()
{
    global $mysqli;
    $tipo = $_REQUEST['tipo'];
    $select = '';
    $consulta  = " SELECT id, nombre FROM autos WHERE 1 = 1 AND tipo = '$tipo' AND id <> 9 ORDER BY nombre ASC ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($consulta);

    $select .= "<option value='Todos'>Todos los autos</option>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $select .= "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['nombre']."</option>";
    }
    echo $select;

}
```

Hola alguien sabe como yo puedo hacer por medio de jquery que mi option value='todos' me filtre por todas la categoria de autos que estoy cargando en la tabla autos?

Comment: Creo que debes formular mejor tu consulta. Si puedes compartir la estructura de las tablas involucrada en la consulta seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: Me suena un tanto ilógico lo que quieres hacer. ¿Puedes explicarlo mejor? Porque lo que yo entiendo al seleccionar una opción con valor "todos" es que seleccione todos los elementos de tu <select>

Comment: la tabla autos se almacenan las categorias de los autos, donde los cargo para filtrar en un select los filtro 1 en 1, pero cuando selecciono una de las categorias y quiero volver a mostrar todos los registros con todas las categorias no puedo, por eso busca una forma de crear otra option con el nombre "todos los autos" para cuando filtre por esa option me vuelva a mostrar todos los registrosde todas las categorias. nose si me logre explicar